# Expectancy value property question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Is it possible that $\mathbb E[X]=2\,$ **and** $\mathbb E[X^2]=3\,$? I tried to figure out some examples, none of them seems to be fulfil equalities. I either can't find an example for it to be possible or don't know how to prove that it is impossible. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case, the variance of $X$ would be $\Bbb E(X^2)-\Bbb E(X)^2=3-2^2=3-4=-1$.
You can't have a negative variance, can you?

Comment: For some reason I didn't think of using the variance ;-) thanks!

Comment: And no, as $X(\omega)^2$ is always positive of course I can't :-)